# Instagram not available among share suggestions in iOS 13

Tags: iphone, ios, sharing, instagram

When I wish to share a Facebook post to Instagram on iPhone running iOS 13, Instagram does not appear among the Share Sheet suggestions, not even when I hit MORE...  I have seen numerous how-tos about hitting EDIT and toggling on the applications listed under Suggestions, but Instagram is not listed at all, although I have the app on my phone and use it all the time.  How can I add it to my Share options?

Comment: As mentioned in this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228177/313842, if the app didn't provide the functionality, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Apps get added to share when you install them. They get removed when you remove them. I would check that your app has uploaded everything to Instagram online and then remove the app.

Once it's gone, power down the phone.
Power it up, and then reinstall the app.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/228177/313842